# jQuery method append: why is the position of the function relevant in the case of multiple parameters?

Tags: jquery, append

It is not even documented (http://api.jquery.com/append/), but it is also possible, that one of the method's **multiple** parameters is a function:

```js
$("#append1").click(function(){
  $("#list1").append(function(){
      return "<li>new</li>";
      },
    "<li>new</li>");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol id="list1">
 <li>old</li>
</ol>
<button id="append1">append1</button>
```

In the absence of documentation, can anyone explain to me, please, why the script only works if the function parameter is the first of the jquery append method parameters, that is: `.append(function, content)`? with the parameters in a different order (that is: `content, function`), the method doesn't work:

```js
$("#append2").click(function(){
  $("#list2").append("<li>new</li>", function(){
      return "<li>new</li>";
      });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol id="list2">
 <li>old</li>
</ol>
<button id="append2">append2</button>
```

I think the question does not specifically concern only the jquery append method.

Comment: I see `.append( content [, content ] )` and it is explained: 
_One or more additional DOM elements, text nodes, arrays of elements and text nodes, HTML strings, or jQuery objects to insert at the end of each element in the set of matched elements._
ditto `.append( function )` _A function that returns an HTML string, DOM element(s), text node(s), or jQuery object to insert at the end of each element in the set of matched elements._

Comment: Allowing content after a function as in your second example seems to be an undocumented feature

Comment: @mplungjan, With this documentation you have reported, why does not this form work?
`.append (content, function)`
And does this form work? `.append(function, content)`

Comment: Only `append(function(){
      return "<li>new</li>";
      },
    "<li>new</li>",
    "<li>new</li>");
})` seems to work, I get error in `.append("<li>new</li>", function(){
      return "<li>new</li>";
      },
    "<li>new</li>",
    "<li>new</li>");`

Answer (score 1):

In the jQuery source code, I found that `arg[0]` is specially handled in `domManip` called from `append`.
So this is a hard-coded behavior.

#### append

https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/821bf34353a6baf97f7944379a6459afb16badae/src/manipulation.js#L340-L347

```
append: function() {
    return domManip( this, arguments, function( elem ) {
        // ...
    } );
},
```

#### domManip

https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/821bf34353a6baf97f7944379a6459afb16badae/src/manipulation.js#L135-L136

```
function domManip( collection, args, callback, ignored ) {
    // ...
        value = args[ 0 ],
        valueIsFunction = isFunction( value );
    // ...
            if ( valueIsFunction ) {
                args[ 0 ] = value.call( this, index, self.html() );
            }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but (because of my limited knowledge) I can not understand your kind answer: it means that jQuery does not allow it and that's it?

Comment: Currently `.append( function [, content ] )` works well, but **In My Opinion** it is a coincidence, and there is no guarantee to keep working even in future versions.